# Linear algebra: Is this proof nonsensical, or am I missing something?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My book has this theorem in a section on the dimension of a vector space:

> If a vector space $V$ has a basis of $n$ vectors, then every basis of V must have exactly $n$ vectors.

Here's their proof:

> Let $B_1$ be a basis of $n$ vectors, and let $B_2$ be any other basis of $V$. Since $B_1$ is a basis and $B_2$ is linearly independent, $B_2$ has no more than $n$ vectors [by a previous theorem in the chapter]. **But since $B_2$ is a basis and $B_1$ is linearly independent, $B_2$ has at least $n$ vectors.** Thus, $B_2$ consists of exactly $n$ vectors.

I've bolded my area of confusion. They do not explain—*at all*—how they arrived at this conclusion. They just say it as if it's true. Is it? I don't understand the logic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem was: if $B$ is a basis and $V$ is a linearly independent set, then $\#B\ge \#V$. Apply this to $B=B_2$ and $V=B_1$ to obtain $\#B_2\ge\#B_1=n$.

Comment: Our book actually didn't present this theorem, which made it incredibly confusing. Thank you

Comment: @AleksandrH It should be the theorem that you're referring to as [by a previous theorem in the chapter].